# thymeleaf 3 form action URL with parameters and get method not working

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf 3 in Spring Boot 2 web app. Below is the form code:

```
<form data-th-action="@{/props/r(pg=3)}" method="get">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"    name="pt" id="p1" value="pr">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="p1">P1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"    name="pt" id="p2" value="pr2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="p2">P2</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class=" mb-4">Search</button>
      </form>
```

Unfortunately when I used method get for the form, it does not append ?pg=3 in the submitted URL, the URL looks like /props/r?  if no checkbox is selected. If checkbox is selected the URL looks like /props/r?pt=p1

the pg=3 part is missing.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have an action `@{/props/r(pg=3)}` -- which translates to `/props/r?pg=3` and your form is also method `get`.  If you have parameters in both the action and the body of the form (and use`method="get"`), browsers will ***not*** combine them. Instead, the parameters of the action are removed and replaced with the paramters in the body of the form.

This is why `?pg=3` is removed and replaced with the checkbox parameters.  Either use `post` instead, or include `pg` as a hidden form element.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting pg as parameter at the form url, consider putting it inside a hidden field like below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="pg" value="3">
```